# Difficulties in calling a method for an http request

Tags: http, ionic-framework, request

I have an error message when I try to make an HTTP request:
"Cannot read property 'get' of undefined"

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {IonicPage, NavController, NavParams} from 'ionic-angular';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {HttpClient} from "@angular/common/http";
import {ContactGdzPage} from "../contact-gdz/contact-gdz";
import {ListeServicePage} from "../liste-service/liste-service";
import {ApiGdz} from "../../services/apiGdz.service";

@IonicPage()
@Component({
    selector: 'page-dashboard',
    templateUrl: 'dashboard.html',
})
export class DashboardPage {

    constructor(private apiGdz: ApiGdz,  public http: HttpClient) {

        this.apiGdz.callApi().then(
            (data) => {

                console.log('ok', data);
            },
            (error) => {
                console.log('!ok', error);
            }
        );
    }
}



import {HttpClient} from "@angular/common/http";


export class ApiGdz {

    public http: HttpClient;

    constructor() {}

    callApi() {
        return new Promise(
            (resolve, reject) => {
                this.http.get('https://swapi.co/api/films').subscribe(
                    (data) => {
                        resolve(data);
                    },
                    (error) => {
                        reject(error);
                    }
                );
            }
        );
    }
}

import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {ErrorHandler, NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {IonicApp, IonicErrorHandler, IonicModule} from 'ionic-angular';
import {SplashScreen} from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import {StatusBar} from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import {MyApp} from './app.component';
import {HomePage} from '../pages/home/home';
import {AuthService} from "../services/auth.service";
import {DashboardPage} from "../pages/dashboard/dashboard";
import {ConnectionPage} from "../pages/connection/connection";
import {HelpPage} from "../pages/help/help";
import {ContactGdzPage} from "../pages/contact-gdz/contact-gdz";
import {ListeServicePage} from "../pages/liste-service/liste-service";
import {ApiGdz} from "../services/apiGdz.service";
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        MyApp,
        HomePage,
        DashboardPage,
        ConnectionPage,
        HelpPage,
        ContactGdzPage,
        ListeServicePage,
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
    ],
    bootstrap: [IonicApp],
    entryComponents: [
        MyApp,
        HomePage,
        DashboardPage,
        ConnectionPage,
        HelpPage,
        ContactGdzPage,
        ListeServicePage,
    ],
    providers: [
        StatusBar,
        SplashScreen,
        {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler},
        AuthService,
        ApiGdz,
    ]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

The problem may be that 'HttpClient' must come from the constructor ... In this case how to instantiate the 'http' object in 'DashboardPage' with parameters?

[image]

Thanks for your help

Comment: You could add it as a parameter to the callApi() function, ie: `callApi(http: HttpClient)`

Comment: Yes, it works like that. Thank you. But I would have liked to know how to also operate the API without having to transfer HttpClient. How to initiate it directly in the ApiGdz class ?

Comment: It is not clear from your question - is the ApiGdz defined as a service? I don't see the @Injectable decorator, but perhaps you just left that out of the details. If it is a service, then just inject HttpClient into it, and inject it (as a service) into DashboardPage. DashboardPage has no need of http in that case. Details [here](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. yes, apiGDZ is a service. I beginner in Ionic and is the concept of decorator is for me still unknown. I will try to learn more about this concept, but if you could show me how to inject as a service? This is different from a 'standard' injection?

Comment: This requires more explanation than a comment will allow.  I'll put together an answer for you later today with an example.

Comment: Great, thank you !

Comment: @GrainedeZèle: dmcgrandle pinged you a couple of times last year to see if their answer helped you. If it did, please consider accepting the answer, by clicking the tick/check mark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me start by saying I am not an Ionic developer so there may well be something specific required for that environment that I am unaware of, I can only speak to the Angular portion of your code.

Given that, I have to make the assumption from what you have posted in your question above that in spite of how it appears, in reality you posted code from 3 DIFFERENT files.  My assumption is that file #1 is the component, probably has a name like `dashboard.component.ts` and looks like the first part of what you posted:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {IonicPage, NavController, NavParams} from 'ionic-angular';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {HttpClient} from "@angular/common/http";
import {ContactGdzPage} from "../contact-gdz/contact-gdz";
import {ListeServicePage} from "../liste-service/liste-service";
import {ApiGdz} from "../../services/apiGdz.service";

@IonicPage()
@Component({
    selector: 'page-dashboard',
    templateUrl: 'dashboard.html',
})
export class DashboardPage {

    constructor(private apiGdz: ApiGdz,  public http: HttpClient) {

        this.apiGdz.callApi().then(
            (data) => {

                console.log('ok', data);
            },
            (error) => {
                console.log('!ok', error);
            }
        );
    }
}
```

Then there is a separate service file (which appears to be imported in the component above), is called `apiGdz.service.ts`, and looks like this:

```
import {HttpClient} from "@angular/common/http";

export class ApiGdz {

    public http: HttpClient;

    constructor() {}

    callApi() {
        return new Promise(
            (resolve, reject) => {
                this.http.get('https://swapi.co/api/films').subscribe(
                    (data) => {
                        resolve(data);
                    },
                    (error) => {
                        reject(error);
                    }
                );
            }
        );
    }
}
```

And finally you also included your base module file, probably called something like  `app.module.ts`, which looks like this:

```
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {ErrorHandler, NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {IonicApp, IonicErrorHandler, IonicModule} from 'ionic-angular';
import {SplashScreen} from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import {StatusBar} from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import {MyApp} from './app.component';
import {HomePage} from '../pages/home/home';
import {AuthService} from "../services/auth.service";
import {DashboardPage} from "../pages/dashboard/dashboard";
import {ConnectionPage} from "../pages/connection/connection";
import {HelpPage} from "../pages/help/help";
import {ContactGdzPage} from "../pages/contact-gdz/contact-gdz";
import {ListeServicePage} from "../pages/liste-service/liste-service";
import {ApiGdz} from "../services/apiGdz.service";
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        MyApp,
        HomePage,
        DashboardPage,
        ConnectionPage,
        HelpPage,
        ContactGdzPage,
        ListeServicePage,
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
    ],
    bootstrap: [IonicApp],
    entryComponents: [
        MyApp,
        HomePage,
        DashboardPage,
        ConnectionPage,
        HelpPage,
        ContactGdzPage,
        ListeServicePage,
    ],
    providers: [
        StatusBar,
        SplashScreen,
        {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler},
        AuthService,
        ApiGdz,
    ]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

If all that is correct, then I would suggest a minor change to both the component and the service.

First the service.  One of the benefits of using services in Angular is that they can hide details from the component such as the fact that you are getting real data from the back-end server via http.  Therefore your service would look something like this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class ApiGdz {

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

    callApi() {
        return new Promise(
            (resolve, reject) => {
                this.http.get('https://swapi.co/api/films').subscribe(
                    (data) => {
                        resolve(data);
                    },
                    (error) => {
                        reject(error);
                    }
                );
            }
        );
    }
}
```

Now your component can be changed to know nothing about http, just rely on the injected service to handle those details.  It would now look something like this:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {IonicPage, NavController, NavParams} from 'ionic-angular';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
// import {HttpClient} from "@angular/common/http";  // <-- DELETE THIS LINE
import {ContactGdzPage} from "../contact-gdz/contact-gdz";
import {ListeServicePage} from "../liste-service/liste-service";
import {ApiGdz} from "../../services/apiGdz.service";

@IonicPage()
@Component({
    selector: 'page-dashboard',
    templateUrl: 'dashboard.html',
})
export class DashboardPage {

    constructor(private apiGdz: ApiGdz) {

        this.apiGdz.callApi().then(
            (data) => {

                console.log('ok', data);
            },
            (error) => {
                console.log('!ok', error);
            }
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your time! It's very clear ! I will do tests. Thanks again !!